# mode_rewrite: example.com/münster -> example.com/index.html?city=münster

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Like described in the title i would like to have clean URLs with mod_rewrite, sadly i didnt manage to write the fitting regex to get the job done i am experimenting with:

1.try:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)$ /index.html?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

2.try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

But none is working properly, even less when it comes to "üöä"

Answer (score 2):

The second one would be better, however, it'll go in a loop as the redirect to `/index.html?city=$1` will be processed as well, and as it matches the RewriteRule it will also be redirected. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

will work better as it ensures it only redirects requests that aren't for existing files or directories. I tried the "münster" example with the above and it redirected as `/index.html?city=m%c3%bcnster` which may or may not be what you require.